# MySql does not throw error when trying to update a non existing record

Tags: mysql

Simple question..

I am working a my stored procedures and I tried to update a record that does not exist in the table. To test it.

I Noticed that MySql executes the SP returning "0 row(s) affected".

I was expecting an error like "not able to update a non existing record" or something like that.

I guess that means us developers have to check that in the stored procedure and throw an error "manually", right?

Here is the procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateAdministrator(
  In Email varchar(50),
  In Pwd blob,
  In LName varchar(30),
  In FName varchar(50),
  In IsActive bit,
  In Deleted bit,
  In RoleTypeId int,
  In Id Int
)
BEGIN
-- Check that Administrator exists in the Administrator table
SET @AdminExist = 0;

PREPARE stmt0 FROM
    "SELECT A.Id INTO @AdminExist FROM Administrator As A WHERE A.Id = ?;";
SET @Id = Id;
EXECUTE stmt0 USING @Id;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt0;   

-- Check that RoleTypeId exists in the RoleType table
SET @RoleTypeExist = 0;

PREPARE stmt FROM
    "SELECT RT.Id INTO @RoleTypeExist FROM RoleType as RT
        WHERE RT.Id = ?;";
SET @RoleTypeId = RoleTypeId;
EXECUTE stmt USING @RoleTypeId;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

IF @AdminExist > 0 AND @RoleTypeExist > 0 THEN    
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM
        "UPDATE Administrator SET Email=?, Pwd=?, LName=?, FName=?, IsActive=?, Deleted=?, RoleTypeId=?
            WHERE Id = ?;";
    SET @Email = Email;
    SET @Pwd = Pwd;
    SET @LName = LName;
    SET @FName = FName;
    SET @IsActive = IsActive;
    SET @Deleted = Deleted;
    EXECUTE stmt2 USING @Email, @Pwd, @LName, @FName, @IsActive, @Deleted, @RoleTypeId, @Id;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

ELSEIF @AdminExist > 0 And @RoleTypeExist = 0 THEN
-- Throw error
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The role for this administrator does not exist...'; 
ELSE 
-- Throw error
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The administrator does not exist';  
END IF;  
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks

All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, it is not an error if you update an empty set. If you want know that the row(s) you are trying to update do not exists, you need to do it yourself.

In a procedure you can use the [ROW_COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count)-function which will contain the number of rows affected.

You can also simplify the procedure quite a bit.

- You do not need to use prepared statements
- Separate procedure parameters with a prefix so they do not mix up with columns
- You better use local variables (DECLARE) instead of user defined variables (@var).
- Also, it's easier just to return an error code (which you then can
  translate to user message in app) than handle the raised errors.

The code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateAdministrator(
in_Email varchar(50),
in_Pwd blob,
in_LName varchar(30),
in_FName varchar(50),
in_IsActive bit,
in_Deleted bit,
in_RoleTypeId int,
in_Id Int
)
BEGIN
declare v_RoleTypeExist int;

-- Check that RoleTypeId exists in the RoleType table
SET v_RoleTypeExist = 0;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_RoleTypeExist
FROM RoleType as RT
WHERE RT.Id = in_RoleTypeId;

IF (v_RoleTypeExist > 0) THEN    
  UPDATE Administrator SET 
    Email=in_Email, 
    Pwd=in_Pwd, 
    LName=in_LName, 
    FName=in_FName, 
    IsActive=in_IsActive, 
    Deleted=in_Deleted, 
    RoleTypeId=in_RoleTypeId
  WHERE Id = in_Id;

  IF (ROW_COUNT() > 0) then
    SELECT '';
  ELSE
    SELECT 'ADMIN_MISSING';  
  END IF;
ELSE 
  SELECT 'ROLE_MISSING';  
END IF;  

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. But if I want a to receive this error in my app, isn't it better to have prepared a custom error message in mysql beforehand?

Comment: You did not show the code for your procedure, but you can simply return an error from procedure to your app.

Comment: I updated the question so you can see the code.. That's what I actually did..just wanted to make sure that was the right way.. ps: don't really see why I got a minus 1 for the question.. isn't stackoverflow also for people who wanna learn?

Comment: @Francois Updated the answer with sample code and some additional tips. As for the minus, could have been that someone put that in prior you showed the code.

Comment: GREAT ! Much clearer..Thanks @slaakso.. 
Two last things..why is it better to use local variables? And why not using prepare statements, I have read it is better to prevent injections

Comment: Injections are only possible when calling SQL directly. You should use prepared statements when you call the procedure, but inside the procedure variables are already parsed so there is no fear of injection. The user defined variables do not have datatype and are alive throughout the session. So, if your procedure calls another procedure / function and they use same user defined variable, it may bring unexpected results. Local variables are as the name says local and only visible in that block. And they have proper datatypes.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation @slaakso.. that answers a lot of questions I have had those past days

Answer (score 0):

In apps I've worked on we typically run two queries.  One to check for existence of the row we are trying to update, and one to actually do the update.

Comment: hi Chris, we need not check the existence for update queries. The query will update if the record exists or it will not do anything. Suppose if we want to know did the query update any records, optionally we can call the ROW_COUNT function as the user has posted in this question.